# Spring batch fault tolerant partitioning step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We have partitioned step which is calling soap server, fetching some styles and splitting those styles in slave steps (one style is one slave step).

Soap communication can fail in partitioner and we would like to give it 3 times to try until whole partitioner step fails. We are using java configuration like this:

```
private Step partitioningStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionedStyleLoadStep")
            .partitioner("styleItemToArticle", stylePartitioner).step(styleItemToArticleStep())
            .aggregator(styleAggregator)
            .taskExecutor(styleLoadTaskExecutor()).gridSize(gridSize).allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
}
```

When we create regular steps with `StepBuilderFactory` after call to `chunk` we get `SimpleStepBuilder` which has `faultTolerant()` method (this allows setting step retry policy and other useful stuff). However on partitioned step after calling `partitioner()` method `PartitionedStepBuilder` is returned which does not have `faultTolerant()` method.

Any ideas how to achieve retry of master partitioned step easily in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we don't have support for making the `Partitioner#partition` method fault tolerant in Spring Batch.  That doesn't mean you can't add the same idea yourself using Spring Retry (that's the same components we use internally).  You can read more about Spring Retry in it's documentation here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry

Comment: Yeah that was my idea exactly after digging some more so actually I have achieved this like that. On each soap call I added retry template to try couple of times and gave me fairly robust way of communication.

Now I am struggling with failing job gracefully instead of throwing exception if retry number is exceeded since I have request to lower amount of logging and partitioner is throwing exception if one of step fails but that is whole another topic.

Thanks for answer.